# Multiple rules with Mod-rewrite

Tags: apache

I'm trying to understand how Mod-rewrite rules work.

I have this right now, first rule works, second one doesn't. What is the solution here?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page=project&name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `L` flag in your first rule, which means "last rule, stop rewriting and do not evaluate any other rules".

Comment: I knew that much, and second rule still doesn't work if i remove it.

Comment: Try to prepend the substitution URL with a slash: `/index.php?category=$1`. In my tests, it worked with a slash, while without a slash `mod_rewrite` did something completely insane: tried to make a HTTP subrequest with my full filesystem path to the `index.php` file as a URL path.

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't make any difference whether i put a slash or not.

Answer (score 0):

The second Rule is not working because of the same regex patterns in both rewriteRules .  So the rule 1 will execute first skipping the other similar rules below.

To avoid this confusion, you can simply change the **path name** and **pattern** for the second Rule.

```
 RewriteRule ^path2/([^/.]+)/?$
```

This accepts a path name of the following format :

```
 /path2/foo
```

**REWRITE**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page=project&name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^path2/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```